# Combine multiple selectors with the same attribute selector into one selector in CSS

Tags: css, sass, less

Is it possible in CSS/SASS/LESS to combine multiple selectors with the same attribute into one selector without repeating the attribute?

For example:

```
div.foo[data="123"] {
  color: red;
}

p.bar[data="123"] {
  color: red;
}

p.bar[data="123"], div.foo[data="123"]{
  color: red;
}
```

Combine them somehow? Such as this invalid scenario:

```
(div.foo, p.bar)[data = "123"] {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:is

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like that:

```
div.foo,
p.bar {
    &[data="123"] {
        color: red;
    } 
}
```

- first step:
  combine your main selectors
- second step:
  adds the data selector